How do I find the intervals where $h(x)$ has a horizontal tangent line from the graph of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ (Calculus)

I included the graph to make the question easier to visualize. The question gives $h(x) = f(g(x))$. On what intervals does $h$ have a horizontal tangent line.
First, I tried using the chain rule to get $f'(g(x)) \cdot g(x)$. However I don't know where to go from there. Since I know a horizontal line tangent is equal to $h'(x)=0$, I tried to set the values to $0$ and evaluate them form the graph. However my answer did not come out correctly.
Any help is appreciated.

You have concept to the answer, but your chain rule is incorrect. $h'(x) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$

Oops yeah I had that for the chain rule in my work I just forgot to add it on my post.

What's the scale of the graph? Without this it' can't be calculated perfectly

@Gwen The graph goes by 1 on the x and y axis.

Assuming $f$ and $g$ are piecewise, you may find formulas for $f$ and $g$, and then $h$.

$$h'(x)=f'(g(x)) g'(x)$$
From the graph, you can see $g(x)$ has a maxima point at $-2$ units from the origin. That is a point where $g'(x)$ is $0$, assuming both functions are continuous and differentiable( it looks like a sharp point). This makes $h'(x)=0$ for that specific point.
Now let $g(x)=t$. If $f(t)$ stays constant, $f'(t)=0$.  Now we see $f(t)$ is constant  from $t=1$ upto $t=5$ atleast, and may continue later.
Thus $f'(t)=0 \forall t \in [1,5]$
Which implies $x\in [g^{-1}(5),g^{-1}(1)]$ as $g$ is a decreasing function in this part.
The scale of the graph hasn't been provided, so I'm assuming both. $x$ and $y$ axes are separated in equal intervals. In that case, maximum value of $g$ is $3$, so we will get $x\in [g^{-1}(3),g^{-1}(1)]=[-3,4]$
Thus for $x \in [-3,4]$ we have a constant value for $f(g(x))$

Nitpicking: f'(t) is not defined at $1$ and $5$. Also, the Chain Rule does most of the work, but it is possible for $f\circ g$ to be differentiable, even though $f$ or $g$ are not differentiable, so there is some special cases to consider.

@Taladris but f(x) is a constant value upto 5 which is parallel to x axis... am I missing something? I'll be really grateful if you help me out here because I didn't know that was a possible thing :")

Sorry, it meant $f$ is not differentiable at $1$ and $-2$. At $5$, it depends on how you interpret the graph: is $f$ assumed to be constant equal to $3$ for every $x\ge 1$, or is the graph stopping at $x=5$?

For the remark about the Chain Rule: let $f(x)=x^2$. Then $g(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ but $f\circ g$ is differentiable at $0$.

As you mentioned, you want $h'(x)=0$, then $0=h'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$, so either $f'(g(x))=0$ or $g'(x)=0$. Check in what intervals that happens. For instance, the simplest case is when $f$ or $g$ are both or either one of them constants in some interval $I$, then $h'$ will be zero on $I$.
